# Syntax Error in ORDER BY clause and data mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, ado

This code gives me a data mismatch error and I can't solve it after hours of searching google. Help would be much appreciated.

The code is to find where "sail number" (a string value) is the same as the caption on the button and where is is from the latest race (hence order desc limit 2)

```
ADOQuery.Close;
ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM MemberRace WHERE SailNumber='+ TButton(sender).Caption + ' ORDER BY Race_ID DESC LIMIT 2;');
ADOQuery.Open;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Ms-Access` doesn't support `Limit`. Use `Top` instead of `Limit`

```
SELECT Top 2 * 
FROM MemberRace 
WHERE SailNumber='+ TButton(sender).Caption + ' 
ORDER BY Race_ID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. That removes the ORDER BY error but still leaves me with the data mismatch in criteria expression. Could you explain what this actually means?

Comment: @DanMassey make sure `TButton(sender).Caption` will also return sttring

Comment: is there an easy way of doing that. I cant find anything on google

Comment: TButton(sender).Caption.ToString()

Comment: @DanMassey - sorry am a `Sql` guy. Just check Yosi comment

Comment: That gives me the error "Record, Object or Class type required"?

Comment: @NoDisplayName thanks for the help been stuck on that for ages :)

Comment: may be you nedd something like 'SELECT * FROM MemberRace WHERE SailNumber='+ '''' + TButton(sender).Caption + '''' + ' ORDER BY Race_ID DESC LIMIT 2;'

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - better post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Now you get:

```
SELECT * FROM MemberRace WHERE SailNumber=5 ORDER BY Race_ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

Because SailNumber is string and 5 is int, you get error.
You should get the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MemberRace WHERE SailNumber='5' ORDER BY Race_ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

Also you need to change `LIMIT` to `TOP`(see @NoDisplayName's answer). So you end up with

```
'SELECT top 2 * FROM MemberRace WHERE SailNumber='+ '''' + TButton(sender).Caption + '''' + ' ORDER BY Race_ID DESC;'
```